# Regular Expression to find given series

Tags: regex

I need to find **English words of Numerics** and **English Words of Durations**. Help me to write Regular expression for that.

1. English words of Numerics => Example => "two hundred thirty"
2. English Words of Durations => Example => "seven years 12 months"

I also tried to write a regular expression for that, but it shoes **0 match**.

Please check.

```
(((\W|^)(one|two|three|....|nineteen|twenty|.....ninety)(\W|$))*((\W|^)(one|two|three|....|nineteen|twenty|.....ninety)(\W|$))*((\W|^)(hundred|thousand|...|billion)(\W|$))*)*
```

Logic is

**[all numbers till 19(0-19) | all tens multiple from 20 till 99|][all numbers till 19(0-19) | all tens multiple from 20 till 99 ][100 | 1000 | 100000]**(Repeat(*))

I only try to complete first case. But it is failing. Help me solve this.

Comment: This might come in handy: http://blog.cordiner.net/2010/01/02/parsing-english-numbers-with-perl/

Comment: Please paste the whole series one|two etc, I'd like to optimize it.

Comment: @thg435 I already made this module, which takes numbers in form of English word, and convert into numericals. My problem is when utterance comes, first we need to get that segment and fire above module. Please help me in that.

Comment: @zx81 please give me some hint.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, middle of the night here. I don't know how to solve your question, sorry. When I said `I'd like to optimize it`, what I meant was that if you had whole series, on that piece of the regex, I would have tried to help "compress it", for instance in the same way that tuesday|thursday|monday can be optimized as `(?:mon|t(?:ue|hur)s)day`. That's all I meant, otherwise I don't know how to solve your regex, sorry. Just offering to help with that piece just in case it helped. Okay, back to sleep.